# Image Processing :Segmenting "zebra" out of image

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

Hey I was trying solve this problem . Where you're asked to segment out "zebra" out of image. Below is the given image.

[image: "Zebra"]

And output should be like this.

[image: Output]

Well I got stuck  at "strips" of zebra cause they may get segmented as separate objects.

Comment: Why don't you add something you have tried?

Comment: Well I'm beginner in IP and I've used some of the standard algorithms provided in openCV . But they also consider strips as objects.

Comment: If you're a beginner you should do other things. One day you'll have gathered enough knowledge to understand what is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In image processing, it is important to look at your image and try to understand the difference between your region of interest, i.e. the zebra, and the rest, i.e. background.

In this example, a clear difference is that the background is rather greenish and the zebra black and white. Therefore, the green channel of the image can be used to extract the background. Afterwards the result can be (non-linearly) cleaned up using some dilation and erosion steps.

A simple and non-perfect segmentation technique is (in Matlab):

```matlab
I = imread('lA196m.jpg');

% plot the original image
figure
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(I)

% calculate the green channel (relative green value)
greenChannel = double(I(:,:, 2))./mean(I(:,:,:), 3);
binary = greenChannel > 1; % apply a thresshold
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(binary);

% remove false positives (backgrounds)
se1 = strel('sphere',20);
binary2 = imdilate(imerode(binary,se1), se1);
subplot(2,2,3)
imshow(binary2);

% add false negatives
se2 = strel('sphere',10);
binary3 = imerode(imdilate(binary2,se2), se2);
subplot(2,2,4)
imshow(binary3);

% calculate & plot the boundary on the original image
subplot(2,2,1)
Bs = bwboundaries(~binary3);
B = Bs{1};
hold on
plot(B(:, 2), B(:, 1), 'LineWidth', 2);
```

[image]